# Quamotion - Search for an element which contains one string and doesn't contain another

Tags: ios, testing, webdriver

I'm testing an iOS app with the Quamotion WebDriver.

I'm trying to identify an element which contains the text '`store`' and doesn't contain the text '`closed`'.

How can I find such an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `contains`, `not` and `and` expressions in XPath to get what you want:

```
//*[contains(@name, 'store') and not(contains(@name, 'closed'))]
```